# VBA get file (object) using recursion

Tags: vba, recursion

The idea is to check all subfolders if certain file is exist in anyone of them. The code finds the file and Debug.Print prints me the Path, but my function "findFile" does not returns the object, just Nothing. I do not think that external var is a good way, so I try to avoid this practice.

```
Function getFile (ByRef outSourceFolder as Object, ByVal reportName as String) as object
Dim myFile as Object
    Set myFile =mylib.findFile(outSourceFolder, reportName) ' always returns Nothing
    If Not (myFile Is Nothing) Then
        Set getFile = myFile 
    End If
End Function

Function findFile(ByRef myFolder As Object, ByVal FileName As String) As Object
Dim iFolder, iFile As Object

    For Each iFile In myFolder.Files
        If InStr(1, iFile.Name, FileName) Then
            Set findFile = iFile
            Debug.Print iFile.Path
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    
' recursive call
    For Each iFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
        Call findFile(iFolder, FileName)
    Next

End Function
```

A resultative recurcion sets the file object, so i get the file, but the rest of calls are like overwites the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem with this:

```
For Each iFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    Set tFile = findFile(iFolder, FileName)
    If Not tFile Is Nothing Then
        Set findFile = tFile
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
```

So I didn't stop the rucursion when needed and that was a problem.